# Access spring profile in log4j2 for spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

How can i access the ${spring.profiles.active} value in log4j2 so that i can append the logfile name based on the profile?

log4j2.xml

`<Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">c:/logs</Property>
        <Property name="targetEnv">${spring.profiles.active}</Property>
    </Properties>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the following configuration and it worked

```
<Property name="targetEnv">${sys:spring.profiles.active}</Property>
```

This might help someone who is facing the same problem

Comment: Will this work if I defined my properties in the way mentioned under number 2 in this web page: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring? In your anser, is this xml string in the configuration file for log4j2 or the spring configuration?

Comment: The above is from log4j2.xml file nothing to do with spring configuration

Comment: It doesn't work. log4j2 doesn't parse the "targetEnv" property: 2021-08-27 17:28:58,088 main DEBUG createProperty(name="targetEnv", value="${sys:spring.profiles.active}")